# Update a combo box to display a specific Index within a JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor, cellrenderer

I have an existing content of values within a JComboBox located within a JTable column. What I am trying to do is read a value in from an exisiting object and update the ComboBox to show this value immediately.

My first attempt was to:

```
 // Sets up properties ComboBox
    propColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(ENV_PROPERTIES_COLUMN);
    propComboBox = new JComboBox();
    propComboBox.addItem(""); // For initial empty string
    constructEnvProperties();

/**
 * Construct Environment Properties comboBox options
 */

     public void constructEnvProperties(){

           Vector<IWM781EnvProfileProperties> recordSet = dataMapperDatabase.getEnvironmentalProperties();

          // Iterate through vector and update combo box
                    for(int i = 0; i < recordSet.size(); i++){

                       logger.debug("Property: " + recordSet.get(i).getProp781Property());
                       propComboBox.addItem(recordSet.get(i).getProp781Property()); 
    }
}
```

Now when I want to update the ComboBox to a selected index I use the code:

```
if(record.getProp785MapProperty().compareTo("") != 0){

    ComboBoxModel model = propComboBox.getModel(); 
    int size1 = model.getSize();

       for (int i1 = 0; i1 < size1; i1++){

            String comparision = record.getRegv785MapRegister();

              if(comparision.equals(propComboBox.getItemAt(i1)))
                 propComboBox.setSelectedIndex(i1);
       }
 }

propColumn.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxCellRenderer());
propColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(propComboBox));
```

When I debug through this it performs exactly as I would expect it to, but the table does not update.

I have tinkered with creating my own DefaultCellEditor to modify some of the functions. This allowed me to have flexibility with selecting specific cells to contain combo boxes and I am currently trying to modify this as a solution.

Comment: Wait, what exactly is the question? And what's not working?

Comment: Apologies, just read back through this and the question doesn't jump out at you, I basically want to update the ComboBox within the JTable by specifying the index, but the table does not update after doing so. It sets itself to index(0) at every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution to the problem just in case anybody else was looking at this and thinks, hmmm, I'm having similar issues. When I set up my TableModel I used the method:

```
   /**
   * Insert row into JTable
   * @param rowData
   */
public void insertRow (Object rowData){
    rows.add((Object[]) rowData);   
}
```

To add rows into the JTable.

When I was inserting rows into the JTable from my main, I was using:

```
 // Data to be inserted into the JTable     
        String[] data = new String[] {seqID, fieldName, type, size, "", value, "", "",""};
        tableModel.insertRow(data);
```

Because of the hard coded "" values, the combo boxes were automatically being assigned to the empty string that existed within the combo box. The quick fix was to create a String variable for each combo box value, perform specific checks on them to ensure there is data to be populated with and voila.

The solution looks simple and I feel quite stupid now .....